# extracting value from Formik Field and performing custom onChange functions

Tags: reactjs, state, formik

I have a formik field. I need to extract the value from this field and run it through a custom onChange function that changes state based on what the user types in. I'm not great with Formik at all. Some help would be highly apprecieted!

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={SetPasswordSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {({ status, isSubmitting, isValid, values }) => (
```

```
            <Field
              name='password'
              required
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange(values.password)}
              component={TextField}
              placeholder={t('authentication:password')}
              type='password'
```

The formik field can not detect my handleChange function, and it is retruning as undefined. Any solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reference to Formik component.
this reference will have methods for doing various operations, from that you can use setFieldValue method to change a particular field.

check [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formikcustomchange-yb1ly)